# OSX drag and drop text ( not file ) to app dock icon

Tags: macos, cocoa, text

I'd like to handle when user drag and drop text ( not file which contain text ) to my app's dock icon. How should i do that?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to accept text dropped on the Dock icon is to implement a service that accepts text.

In your Info.plist:

```
<dict>
    <key>NSMenuItem</key>
    <dict>
        <key>default</key>
        <string>Search in HoudahSpot</string>
    </dict>
    <key>NSMessage</key>
    <string>search</string>
    <key>NSPortName</key>
    <string>HoudahSpot</string>
    <key>NSRequiredContext</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSServiceCategory</key>
        <string>public.text</string>
    </dict>
    <key>NSSendTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>NSStringPboardType</string>
    </array>
    <key>Service description</key>
    <string>Starts a HoudahSpot search for the selected text</string>
</dict>
```

In your application delegate:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [NSApp setServicesProvider:self];
}

- (void)search:(NSPasteboard *)pboard userData:(NSString *)data error:(NSString **)error
{
    NSArray *types = [pboard types];

    if ([types containsObject:NSStringPboardType]) {
        NSString *searchString = [pboard stringForType:NSStringPboardType];

        NSLog(@"%@", searchString);
    }
}
```

You can also catch the event by registering for it in -applicationWillFinishLaunching:

```
NSAppleEventManager     *appleEventManager  = [NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager];

    [appleEventManager setEventHandler:self
                           andSelector:@selector(handleOpenContentsEvent:withReplyEvent:)
                         forEventClass:kCoreEventClass
                            andEventID:kAEOpenContents];
```

And handling it:

```
- (void)handleOpenContentsEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)event withReplyEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)replyEvent
{
    NSString *string = [[event paramDescriptorForKeyword:keyDirectObject] stringValue];

    NSLog(@"%@", string);
}
```

You still need to declare a service in your Info.plist for the drop to be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Swift recipe:

In Info.plist

---

```
<key>NSServices</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>NSSendTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>NSStringPboardType</string>
        </array>
        <key>NSMessage</key>
        <string>droppedText</string>
        <key>NSMenuItem</key>
        <dict>
            <key>default</key>
            <string>Text Drop</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

In AppDelegate

---

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    print(kUTTypeUTF8PlainText)
    NSApplication.sharedApplication().servicesProvider = self
}

//When text is dragged over the icon
func droppedText(pboard: NSPasteboard, userData:String, error: NSErrorPointer)
{
    if let pboardString = pboard.stringForType(NSStringPboardType){
        print(pboardString)
    }
}
```

Comment: This got me 90% of the way there. (Even mixing this in with swiftUI). One notable exception: Using this answer mostly out of the box yielded this error: `Cannot find service provider for selector droppedText:userData:error: or droppedText:: for service droppedText`. I had to make the first argment unnamed in order for it to work. Example: `func droppedText( _ pboard: NSPasteboard, userData:String, error: NSErrorPointer)`. It might be because I have an object that exists outside the app delegate that I was using it in?

Comment: @KellyHuberty Apple most likely did some refactoring. My answer was added in 2017